# How to play Vimeo private and public videos in iOS app(swift 3)

Tags: swift3, vimeo-api, vimeo-player

I am a premium user of Vimeo, I have to integrate the Vimeo player in my iOS(Swift 3) app.
I am using below HTML to play Vimeo in-app webview, but it's playing the only public video(private videos are not playing anymore)

I am using below HTML:

" Title https://player.vimeo.com/video/" + "\(VI)?autoplay=1&muted=0" + "' width='100%' height= 100%  frameborder='0' webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen> https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js'>   "

Comment: Can you post the Swift code you are using to fetch the video? Where does the `VI` value come from?

Comment: I am getting the Vimeo URL like:
https://vimeo.com/129552711 (public URL)
https://vimeo.com/308189520/c0ace02792 (private URL)
VI is the Vimeo Vimeo ID
but in the second URL which one is the Vimeo id, I don't know(this URL formate come if Vimeo URL is private)

Comment: For private videos you will need to authenticate to get a playable URL, and you will likely want to use the `VimeoNetworking` library for that https://www.github.com/vimeo/VimeoNetworking

Comment: I download the demo app from the above given URL. I passed all the credentials in
let appConfiguration = AppConfiguration(
  clientIdentifier: "Your client identifier goes here",
  clientSecret: "Your client secret goes here",
  scope: [.Public, .Private, .Interact] //replace with your scopes)
then how to pass appConfiguration object in html url. 
I Have already written the HTML  Which I am using to play Vimeo.

Comment: Try adding the `.VideoFiles` scope and see if that helps

Comment: can you give me demo app, if you have

Comment: If you add the code you have, and what you have tried so far, I can try to help.